# Image Path in createTableViewRow in Titanium

Tags: image, titanium

I am creating table view in titanium. I got a problem here.

I am not getting image in leftImage of table row.

Here is the code:

```
var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView();
var section = Titanium.UI.createTableViewSection();
var row1 = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();
row1.leftImage : 'android/images/res/radio.jpg',
row1.title = "Nuts";
row1.color = "red";
section.add(row1);
data.push(section);
table1.setData(data);
```

I am getting the complete row but Image is not displaying. I tried it a lot. Waiting for your feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be some issue related to the path. Just test it by putting the image in other directory like Resourses/images/radios.jpg and see.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the way you provided I had some problem with too. Better try it with an imageview and position it. Something like this:

```
var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    url: Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + 'android/images/res/radio.jpg',
    left: 5
});
row1.add(image);
```

Make sure you use the root path for anything, especially in Android. You can do that with `Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory` which is the path to the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

there must be some issue with your image path. the code below works for me:

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'home',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});
var data = [];
var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView();
var section = Titanium.UI.createTableViewSection();
var row1 = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    leftImage : 'images/KS_nav_ui.png',
    title : "Nuts",
    color : "red"
});
section.add(row1);
data.push(section);
table1.setData(data);
win1.add(table1);

win1.open();
```